# getting python pyobcd installed

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm a little lost on how to get **pyodbc** installed in my computer.
I have python 3.6.1
The link 
http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011656
pointed me to another link
https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc

Which is vague.
I'm used to downloading and running an exe for install.
This link is unclear and says all I have to do is:

```
"pip install pyodbc"
```

What exactly do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Check out the readme on that same page, it links to a very specific [install guide.](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install) . More information is available on the [pyobcd wiki](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not mentioned which OS you are using,
I will assume that you are on windows (as you have mentioned that you are used to install using .exe).

Firstly you need to know what a pip is:
pip is basically a package manager for python packages used to install 3 rd party packages which do not bundle along with the python distribution.
On linux pip comes pre installed also if you are using python version 3.4 onwards or python 2.7.9 you will be having pip pre installed on your system.
All you have to do it to open the command prompt issue the command

> pip install package-name(pyobdc here)

it will do the job.
If you do not find pip in your distribution you can refer this link
[How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Comment: Ok, I am one step further. The pip was actually under Scripts subfolder.  But when I run it, I get a fatal error.  I will post as a separate question....

Answer (score 0):

open cmd in your computer and type
pip install pyobdc

Comment: Hi @Luv, welcome to the wonderful world of Python. If it can't find the command `pip` from the command line, you may not have checked to include Python in your path during the Python 3.6.1 installation. There's a handy checkbox on the Windows installer for including Python in your path, which I highly recommend checking. I believe you can run the installer again and check the box.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there and welcome to python programming. Basically python comes with its package installer so either you can go to any interpreter that you are using and type `pip install pyobdc` or use the command prompt in windows and type in `pip install pyobdc`. This would install your module and just remember to put `import pyobdc` at the top of the code if you want to use this package. Further information can be found on [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/)